# json image Angular framework

Tags: javascript, json, angular, api, ionic-framework

i export data from json to the text is show and everything good in HTML but when i need to export the image from json I can't show it in HTML

how can I put this image JSON in ionic framework

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos

```
"thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/771796"
```

my codes for the rest api provider

```
getImg() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.get(this.apiUrl+'/photos').subscribe(data => {
      resolve(data);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  });
}
```

page.ts

```
  getImg() {
    this.restProvider.getImg()
    .then(data => {
      this.photos = data;
      console.log(this.photos);
    });
  }
```

page.html

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list inset>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let user of users">
      <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
      <p>{{user.email}}</p>
      <img [src]="photo.thumbnailUrl">
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: angularjs or angular ?

Comment: you are looping on users `*ngFor="let user of users"` and exacting an image from `photos` array?where you define `photo` in `photo.thumbnailUrl`?

Comment: when I Add   

 <ion-item *ngFor="let photo of photos">

      <img md-card-image src="{{photo.thumbnailUrl}}">
    </ion-item> it show all images in json and it not look like in the div or element for the first item i want to put all togther in the same div or ionic card

Comment: how can i show only 1 image from json in same div for the list or item ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you write wrong code, change photo with user, if your image exists in **users** array

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
      h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
      <p>{{user.email}}</p>
      <img [src]="user.thumbnailUrl">
</div>
```

and if your image exists in **photo array**, then code is something like below...

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
      h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
      <p>{{user.email}}</p>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let photosrc of photo">
      <img [src]="photosrc.thumbnailUrl">
</div>
```

**Thanks**